# Logic of for loop using with array to access elements of the array in java

Tags: java, arrays, debugging, data-structures

My code to access elements of array using for loop. The output of the program is `[19,17,15]` which are the elements of array `int a[] = { 12, 15, 16, 17, 19, 23 }`. Output after following code is written:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        int a[] = { 12, 15, 16, 17, 19, 23 };
        for (int i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            if (i % 3 != 0) {
                --i;
            }
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Algorithm:

1. Iteration 1: `i=5` so `a[5]=23`. "if statement" gets true and `--i` execute. so `i=4`. Hence, `a[4]=19` will get print as first element in output.
2. Iteration 2: `i=3` so `a[3]=17`. "if statement" gets true again and `--i` should execute but it skips that condition as I tried using debugging tool to see how it is working. And output is `a[3]=17` which is wrong I think.

Could you help me in understanding why it gives 17 as output? As in my opinion it should skip that part.

Comment: If `i = 3`, then `i % 3` is `0`. That would mean your if statement becomes false and not true.

Comment: And since the if statement is false, that would explain the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Your `if` statement doesn't check `a[i] % 3 != 0` - it checks `i % 3 != 0`. In the first iteration `i` is 5 and `i % 3 != 0` is true. In the second iteration `i` is 3 and `i % 3 != 0` is false and therefore `i` is not decremented and `a[3]` gets printed.

Comment: ```a%b``` is the modulo operator. It returns the reminder of ```a/b```

Comment: Your problem is that you decrement `i` twice (_once as a result of the condition and again as an an unconditional part of your forloop_). Instead replace the `if` body with `continue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a step by step explanation. `(i % 3 != 0)` checks to see if `i is not divisible by 3`. Also note that in this context, your post and pre-decrements of `i` are not relevant as the outcome would be the same no matter how they are decremented.

```
 i = 5;
 i not divisible by 3 so i-- = 4
 print a[4] = 19
 i-- at end of loop = 3
 i is divisible by 3 so i remains 3
 print a[3] = 17
 i-- at end of loop = 2
 i not divisible by 3 so i-- = 1
 print a[1] = 15
 i-- = 0 so loop terminates.
```

Answer (score -1):

In iteration 2, where i=3 the condition is false, since 3 % 3 = 0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).